# Bokeh CheckboxGroup with changing content - container size

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a dynamically updated CheckboxGroup, whose container re-sizes well as long as I don't put the widget into a more complex settings of rows or columns. Once the layout becomes more complex, the widgets overlap when dynamically adding entries to the CheckboxGroup (size stays on the original height). Here's some code for testing:

```
import sys, os
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Div, Button


def guiBuildLayout(guiElements):
    layout = column(guiElements.values())
    return layout

def update_checkbox():
    checkbox.labels += checkbox.labels

guiElements = OrderedDict()

divHTML = '<p>TEST.</p>'
guiElements.update({'test': row(Div(text=divHTML, height=30))})

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'])

guiElements.update({'chbx': row(children=[checkbox])})

button = Button(label='Grow!')
button.on_click(update_checkbox)
guiElements.update({'but': button})

divHTML2 = '<p>TEST2.</p>'
guiElements.update({'test2': row(Div(text=divHTML2, height=30))})

mainLayout = guiBuildLayout(guiElements)

curdoc().add_root(mainLayout)
curdoc().title = "Check Checkboxgroup"
```

If the checkbox group is not put into a row in the first place (before adding to the column of widgets), re-sizing works just fine.
Do you know of any way to avoid this?